# Why is the CSS padding not displayed?

Tags: html, css, padding

The following is the code for index.html

```css
figure,
figcaption {
  display: block;
}
figcaption {
  color: black;
}
#profile_photo {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#profile_photo figure {
  padding: 6px 8px 10px 8px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile_photo">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200X350" alt="Profile Photo" height="350px" />
    <figcaption>Welcome</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

The padding for the image is not being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, I'm trying to complete Step 2 [of the following tutorial](http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-polaroid.htm)

Comment: It's displayed. Put some background color for blocks to see that.

Comment: It is being displayed. Set a background colour on the figure element and you can see it around the edge of the image.

Comment: Which browser do you use? Seems to work in Firefox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being displayed as others have commented, you just have no background color in order to see it. If you use inspection tools you'll see the padding is there.

```
#profile_photo figure{
    padding: 6px 8px 10px 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/jPpowz)

Answer (score 0):

the padding is actually showing
but if you want to give some space between the image and the space between image and text try assigning the padding to the  tag

```
img{ padding: 6px 8px 10px 8px; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try putting

`#profile_photo img` instead of `#profile_photo figure` since the HTML might not render `<figure>` tag

Comment: why? are you in old browser?